# Group a list of strings by length

Tags: java, stream

Is it possible to write this using the stream element? I can get the most of it with stream but it is the add adding string to list which is in the map that I am caught on.

```java
/**
 * Given a list of strings, returns a map where the keys are the unique strings lengths found in the list and the values are the strings matching each length
 * [hello,world,cat,ambulance] would return {5 -> [hello, world], 3 -> [cat] -> 3, 9 -> [ambulance]}
 * @param strings
 * @return
 */
public Map<Integer,List<String>> mapLengthToMatchingStrings(List<String> strings){

    Map<Integer,List<String>> mapILS = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    for (String str : strings) {
        int length = str.length();

        if (mapILS.containsKey(length)) {
            // Add str to list at key
            //Get list at key
            List<String> rs = mapILS.get(length);
            //Add str to list
            rs.add(str);
            //Update key in map
            mapILS.put(length, rs);
        }else {
            // Add new key list to map
            //Create list
            List<String> rs = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Add string
            rs.add(str);
            //Add key and list to map
            mapILS.put(length, rs);
        }
    }       
    return mapILS;
}
```

Comment: For anyone voting to close this question: yes, it could be worded better. But the code seems to work and there's a description in the title & comments. The specific request is usually off-topic, but it would've been the likely outcome in a review anyway. John, for your next question, please read [our FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only possible but also a great example of how functional programming can make code much simpler and readable:

```
  public Map<Integer,List<String>> mapLengthToMatchingStrings(List<String> strings){
        return strings.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
    }
```

(The `distinct` part is optional, regarding whether you want duplicates in the lists)

Comment: Wow, that is great. So to the point.